# Como colocar a regra de validação apenas quando for salvar e não validar no update no Django admin com python?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, model-validation

Estou desenvolvendo em Django a seguinte aplicação de gerenciamento de curso, no cadastro de uma turma eu tenho um cadastro informando a quantidade de vagas para médicos e acadêmicos, e na inscrição eu preciso, que o sistema aceite apenas a quantidade relativa ao que foi disponibilizado de vagas. Estou fazendo essa regra dentro do admin do django. segue o código

```
class Inscricao(models.Model):
    Pessoa = models.ForeignKey(Pessoa, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    Turma = models.ForeignKey(Turma, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    Inscricao = models.CharField(db_column='NU_INSCRICAO', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    numero_sorteio = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column='NUMERO_SORTEIO', blank=True, null=True) 
    Presente = models.BooleanField(db_column='PRESENTE', blank=True, null=True) 
    dt_sorteio = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DT_SORTEIO', blank=True, null=True)  
    Certificado = models.ForeignKey(Certificado, blank= True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    dt_emissao_certificado = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DT_EMISSAO_CERTIFICADO', blank=True, null=True)  
    dt_cadastro = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DT_CADASTRO', blank=True, null=True, auto_now_add = True)       
    dt_alteracao = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DT_ALTERACAO', blank=True, null=True, auto_now = True)   
    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Inscrição'
        verbose_name_plural='Inscrições'
    def clean(self):
        qtd_vaga_academico=sum([e.quantidade for e in TurmaRegraVaga.objects.filter(Turma__id_turma=self.Turma.id_turma,Regra_vaga__Regra_vaga='Acadêmicos')]) 
        qtd_vaga_medico=sum([e.quantidade for e in TurmaRegraVaga.objects.filter(Turma__id_turma=self.Turma.id_turma,Regra_vaga__Regra_vaga='Médicos')]) 
        qtd_vaga_medico_academico=sum([e.quantidade for e in TurmaRegraVaga.objects.filter(Turma__id_turma=self.Turma.id_turma,Regra_vaga__Regra_vaga='Médicos e Acadêmicos')]) 

        if  self.Pessoa.Tipo_pessoa == 'A' and qtd_vaga_academico <= Inscricao.objects.filter(Turma__id_turma=self.Turma.id_turma,Pessoa__Tipo_pessoa = 'A').count(): 
            raise ValidationError('Não há mais vagas disponíveis.')
        if  self.Pessoa.Tipo_pessoa == 'M' and qtd_vaga_medico <= Inscricao.objects.filter(Turma__id_turma=self.Turma.id_turma,Pessoa__Tipo_pessoa = 'M').count(): 
            raise ValidationError('Não há mais vagas disponíveis.')
```

Porém com esse código quando eu vou alterar informando que o aluno está presente ele também faz a validação dizendo que não há mais vagas, pq ele valida tanto no salvar quanto no update, como faço para deixar essa regra apenas para o salvar e não para o update. Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Pensando um pouco aqui consegui uma solução, não sei se tem um comando específico no django para identificar quando é insert ou update, mas eu coloque no if para verificar se o id tem ou não algo dentro se não tiver é insert se tiver é update dessa forma consegui fazer a validação. Se alguém tiver outra visão gentileza compartilhar. Segue solução.

```
def clean(self):
    qtd_vaga_academico=sum([e.quantidade for e in TurmaRegraVaga.objects.filter(Turma__id_turma=self.Turma.id_turma,Regra_vaga__Regra_vaga='Acadêmicos')]) 
    qtd_vaga_medico=sum([e.quantidade for e in TurmaRegraVaga.objects.filter(Turma__id_turma=self.Turma.id_turma,Regra_vaga__Regra_vaga='Médicos')]) 
    qtd_vaga_medico_academico=sum([e.quantidade for e in TurmaRegraVaga.objects.filter(Turma__id_turma=self.Turma.id_turma,Regra_vaga__Regra_vaga='Médicos e Acadêmicos')]) 

    if  self.id_inscricao is None and self.Pessoa.Tipo_pessoa == 'A' and qtd_vaga_academico <= Inscricao.objects.filter(Turma__id_turma=self.Turma.id_turma,Pessoa__Tipo_pessoa = 'A').count(): 
        raise ValidationError('Não há mais vagas disponíveis.')
    if  self.id_inscricao is None and self.Pessoa.Tipo_pessoa == 'M' and qtd_vaga_medico <= Inscricao.objects.filter(Turma__id_turma=self.Turma.id_turma,Pessoa__Tipo_pessoa = 'M').count(): 
        raise ValidationError('Não há mais vagas disponíveis.')
```